# IE7 and Site Rendering

Tags: support

In some cases, there is a rendering issue with user pages or non-Question pages, where the left boundary of the page shows up as extremely far off the left edge of the window, and there is no way to fix this from a client perspective.  I believe that this is a bug, but as this occurs on my work machine, I cannot screenshot the issue.

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: @Marco i cant get you a screenshot, my workplace does not allow me to upload from their systems.

Answer (score 2):

Is the site still readable? If it is you probably won't see this fixed, [per Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68303/badges-publicist-badge/68327#68327):

> We're starting to put IE7 in our "we will guarantee the site works, but there may be visual inconsistencies from time to time that you would not experience in a more modern browser" bucket.
>
> As long as the site works, we aren't fixing cosmetic issues with IE7 any more.

Comment: With the exception of the pages i stated earlier which dont have this issue, the other pages in the site(s) are entirely unreadable.  This occurs on ALL SE sites, and also on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect an Ubuntu site to work in IE7?

IE7 is our *absolute minimum browser* supported on the network, and only in the sense that we want the site to work but make no guarantees that it will look good or correct.

For this site in particular, our minimum bar of IE7 seems not very relevant.

Comment: i bring it up because my work environment forces me to use IE7 and Windows... i'm a Linux guy every other time of the day though

Comment: also, I posted this to deal with an SE-wide issue - the issue occurs on EVERY SE site, and @Marco said that I could post here and the SE staff would see it

Comment: @TheEvilPhoenix And the SE staff have seen it :)